# Sorting a list based on the occurrence of a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take in a list of strings and sort them by the occurrence of a character using the python function `sort()` or `sorted()`. I can do it in many lines of code where I write my own sort function, I'm just unsure about how to do it so easily in python

In terms of `sorted()` it can take in the list and the key

```py
l = ['a', 'wq', 'abababaaa']
#I think it's something like this, I know I'm missing something
sorted(l, key = count('a'))
```

The expected result would be

```
['wq', 'a', 'abababaaa']
```

Comment: @PV8 - That isn't a duplicate

Comment: @PV8 (not OP) not a duplicate, this guy wants to sort based on how many times the character 'a' appears

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just missing the lambda for the sorting key so you have a way to reference the list item that needs occurrences of a counted

```
sorted(l, key = lambda x: x.count('a'))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sorted(l, key=lambda r: r.count('a'))
```